# Windows Forms: Keep application in "Applications" tab while hiding the first form

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

Let's say I'm writing a Windows Forms (.NET Framework 3.5) application which shows the first form in the usual way:

```
Application.Run(new Foo());
```

At this point the title and icon of this application are correctly shown in the "Application" tab of the task manager and I'm happy.
Then somewhere in Foo I show a second form while hiding the first:

```
Bar bar = new Bar();

try
{
    Visible = false;
    bar.ShowDialog();
}
finally
{
    Visible = true;
    bar.Dispose();
}
```

This works as expected, but as long as Foo is hidden, the entry in the "Applications" tab of the task manager for the application also disappears. Unfortunately some users and third party tools are terribly confused by this.

Is there a way to still display the icon and name of an application in the task manager if the "main form" of the application is not visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Ancient smoke-and-mirrors trick I've done in the past... leave the form visible, but set its LOCATION to something like top = 0, left = -5000, so it won't be in the visible screen area

Comment: Thanks. This way of handling the problem feels incredible hacky, but that seems to be the only way. I also tried minimzing the main form but that creates a whole new group of problems ...

Answer (score 0):

If bar is inherited from the windows form. Have you tried adding the same icon to that form?

Comment: Yes, Bar derives from Form. Sorry for not making that clear.  The second form uses the same icon already.

Answer (score 0):

This is **by-design** of Windows, if the main launched window is hidden, its entry in the Applications tab is hidden too.

I don't think you can do that, the opposite is doable though.

The reason behind that I guess, is that when you hide a window you're actually making it act or be used as a service/background application.